# How to do PCA on multiple images by flattening the tensors?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimension, reduction

I have an array of tensors for a single image. I want to flatten the vectors and perform PCA on the same.

The below is the code to extract the tensors on a single image :

```
bottle_neck_model_tensors = bottle_neck_model([im_resize])[0]
bottle_neck_model_tensors
```

I want to do the same on multiple images and also flatten the array. later perform PCA on the array.

Can anyone help me with this?

## Code For multiple images

```
import glob
import cv2 as cv

path = glob.glob(".../SampleImages*.jpg")
    
cv_img = []
for img in path:
   n = cv.imread(img)
   #print(n.shape)
   im_resize = cv2.resize(n , (1024 ,1024))
   im_resize = np.expand_dims(im_resize, axis = 0)
   cv_img.append(im_resize)
   bottle_neck_model_tensors = bottle_neck_model([im_resize])[0]
```

I want to improvise this code and flatten the vectors. I am reshaping because the model I created from the extracted layers is of shape `( None, 128, 128, 512)` and the input image to the model is `1024, 1024, 3`.